# DOMException: Failed to execute 'show' on 'PaymentRequest': PaymentRequest.show()

Tags: javascript, payment

I came across Javascript's Payment API and thought of understanding it. So, I have generated a sample code for the API to check the working. But I am getting this error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'show' on 'PaymentRequest': PaymentRequest.show() requires either transient user activation or delegated payment request capability
```

while using the code. No idea what is wrong with it

Here is the sample code I am using:

```js
if (window.PaymentRequest) {
  // Create a payment method object for the supported payment methods
  const methodData = [{
    supportedMethods: ['basic-card'],
    data: {
      supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard'],
      supportedTypes: ['debit', 'credit']
    }
  }];

  // Create the payment details object with the total amount
  const details = {
    total: {
      label: 'Total amount',
      amount: {
        currency: 'USD',
        value: '50.00'
      }
    }
  };

  // Create the payment request object
  const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(methodData, details);
  // Show the payment UI to the user and wait for their response
  paymentRequest.show()
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response: ", response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Payment request failed: ', error);
    });
} else {
  console.error('Payment Request API is not supported');
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaymentRequest/show#security: _"Transient user activation is required. The user has to interact with the page or a UI element in order for this feature to work."_ - you can not just call the show method "out of the blue", it requires that the user clicks somewhere first to trigger the process.